# How do I update the Icon of a program running from /usr/local/bin on the Dock?

Tags: dock, macvim

I often run mvim from iTerm, and it pops up on the Dock with the default vim icon. A friend gave me a nice icon for mvim, how do I go about updating the icon for mvim launched from a console?

Comment: When you refer to the "Icon bar", you are talking about the [Dock](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=mac+dock&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1068&bih=865&tbm=isch&tbnid=krdFXIIGlh3C8M:&imgrefurl=http://crossgeared.com/%3Ftag%3D10-5&docid=cqwkr4ctkTRBGM&imgurl=http://crossgeared.com/stuff/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/dock.jpg&w=500&h=313&ei=wJSoTsycH5DctwfO2r0X&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=99&vpy=242&dur=90&hovh=178&hovw=284&tx=134&ty=148&sig=110211042946095577421&page=3&tbnh=126&tbnw=201&start=32&ndsp=16&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:32) correct?

Comment: Just to clarify: the command you are running from /usr/local/bin is mvim, the executed application at the end is /Applications/MacVim.app. The only icon you can change is the one of MacVim.app but it then will be changed as well if you run the application directly.

Comment: I have changed the icon for MacVim.app using the "GetInfo" method described below by canderson. However, when I run the /usr/local/bin mvim, it still pops up the old one. I suspect that at some point, i've installed to mvims. One via Homebrew and one from source.

Answer (score 3):

There's two main ways of changing the icon for an application.

The first (and free) way is to navigate to the application itself (most likely in your /Applications folder). Right-click the app (MacVim.app), and select "Get Info". Then, drag the new icon onto existing icon displayed in the Get Info pane. In this Adium example, you'd drag the new icon over the Adium duck icon. A password pane will most likely pop up - enter your password and you should be all set.

[image]

The other way is to buy [CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) for $30. CandyBar is a much easier to way to manage large scale icon changes, plus provides an interfaces for organized vast icon libraries. But if you are just looking to change one icon, it is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

[LiteIcon](http://freemacsoft.net/) is a free alternative to Candybar. I've used it quite a bit and I really like it.